# Issue with Oracle stored Procedure when invoked with Hibernate - ORA-01001: invalid cursor

Tags: oracle, hibernate, plsql, cursor

I am facing a strange problem.

I have created an oracle stored procedure and tested it in SQL Developer and it works fine.

Now when I tried to call it using Hibernate 3,it shows the below mentioned error message. Can someone help me what I am missing? The line number it is giving points to the line where `myCursor2` is being closed.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "MystoredProcedure", line 56
```

My stored procedure looks as below.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MystoredProcedure (
    four input arguemnts and 
     one output variable all are numbers
) AS 
  cursor myCursor2 is
     select statement;
  CURSOR myCursor1 is
     select statement;
  Variables to hold data  
BEGIN
  OPEN myCursor1;      
  LOOP
      FETCH myCursor1 into variables;
      EXIT WHEN myCursor1%NOTFOUND;

        insert data into a set of tables.

      OPEN myCursor2;
      LOOP
          FETCH myCursor2 into variables;
          EXIT WHEN myCursor2%NOTFOUND;
          insert data into some other tables
      END LOOP;  

  end Loop;
  insert into another table

  CLOSE myCursor2;
  CLOSE myCursor1;

END MystoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you close `myCursor2` after each iteration of the outer loop, not only once after it is done? And which line is line 56 by the way?

Comment: Line 56 is at code "CLOSE myCursor2;". I have tried closing the cursor2 inside the outer loop, but landed up in a different error. But I got your point. Will try it again and come back.

Comment: I's very likely that you are facing that error simply because `myCursor1` returns no rows. When it happens you will exit the outer loop immediately and `myCursor2` will never be opened, so when you try to close it, the error pops up. So, before closing a cursor, you may check if it has been opened `if myCursor2%isopen then close myCursor2; end if;`

Comment: I have to use the same data returned by cursor2 for processing all the records in custor1. we can treat that as a kind of reference data. This is the reason I tried closing cursor2 outside the loop. Now I tried to move the close cursor2 inside the outer loop. Now I got the below error in java but works fine in SQL Developer. Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next

Comment: @ Nicholas Krasnov, But it is working fine when tested with SQL Developer. I have only one row returned by cursor1 and 3 rows returned by cursor2